# Copy footer content to next section in python docx

Tags: python-docx

After adding a new section to a python-docx document, I want to reuse (clone) the footer of the previous section and later modify/add elements for the new section only. The footer contains tables and paragraphs including fields (page numbers, document properties...).

I got stuck to find a way to copy all elements of the old footer to the new one.

```py
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.section import WD_SECTION, WD_ORIENT

# open exisitng document
document = Document("...")

# add a new section
document.add_section(WD_SECTION.NEW_PAGE)

# change orientation of the new section
new_section = document.sections[-1]
new_width, new_height = new_section.page_height, new_section.page_width
new_section.orientation = WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE
new_section.page_width = new_width
new_section.page_height = new_height

# Use a separate footer for the new section
new_section.footer.is_linked_to_previous = False

# copy over the footer of the previous section
new_section.footer = document.sections[-2].footer
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^How?
# ...
```